# what characterset to use when i create my database

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

So I am doing a lot of php tutorials and I always wonder when creating my different DBs...

What charset should I be using? Depending on what DB interface I use it seems to default to different options.

So what is the most common one I should use for basic programing... Or can someone point me to a good guide to charsets in MySql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you've got a good reason not to, always default to UTF-8 (Unicode).

Comment: UTF-8 is better for localization. Don't forget to update ODBC connector on Windows MySQL - the default one doesn't support UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I always aim for UTF-8 or similar.